# convert string to decimal or float mysql

Tags: mysql, casting, decimal

i have the next problem,
i have a table with a string column, but i need convert this column in decimal or float.
I tried with cast and convert but doesn't work
example

input

```
3.50
7.10
18.50
27.00
46.50
46.90
117.90
226.70
274.70
Not available
Not available
```

tried

```
select cast(price as decimal(16,2)) from products
```

output

```
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
```

i see this warnings

> Warning: #1918 Encountered illegal value '' when converting to DECIMAL

> Warning: # 1292 Wrong truncated DECIMAL value:

I need later multiplier this column with another column

Comment: Just add 0; not cast or convert is needed.  Even adding 0 _may_ not be necessary if you use the string in a numeric context.  Do you also need `TRIM()`?

Answer (score 2):

If you add simple a 0 to the value you get a float or decimal which you can cast or usde directly
everythin that is not a number is cobverteed to 0, but you can Replace Not available with another number

> ```
> CREATE TABLE textvalue
>     (`Input` varchar(13))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO textvalue
>     (`Input`)
> VALUES
>     ('3.50'),
>     ('7.10'),
>     ('18.50'),
>     ('27.00'),
>     ('46.50'),
>     ('46.90'),
>     ('117.90'),
>     ('226.70'),
>     ('274.70'),
>     ('Not available'),
>     ('Not available')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CAST(Input + 0 AS DECIMAL(12,2))FROM textvalue
> ```
>
> ```
> | CAST(Input + 0 AS DECIMAL(12,2)) |
> | -------------------------------: |
> |                             3.50 |
> |                             7.10 |
> |                            18.50 |
> |                            27.00 |
> |                            46.50 |
> |                            46.90 |
> |                           117.90 |
> |                           226.70 |
> |                           274.70 |
> |                             0.00 |
> |                             0.00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=679bf92d3a5f6dc1ac550a0fd10e5068)*

Comment: This was the only suggestion that worked when the column contained some empty/null/blank rows!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select convert(price, decimal(16,2)) from products
```